# Laravel running multiple queries instead of join in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I am trying to run join between my pages table and users table. Means one user can create multiple pages and in pages table `created_by` column belongs to my users table column `id`.

**Table Structure:**

```
---------------------------------------------
  id  | page_title | page_desc | created_by |    
---------------------------------------------
  1   |  Testing   | Descripti |      1     |
---------------------------------------------
  2   |  New Page  | Desc      |      2     |
```

**User table**

```
-------------------------------------------
 id  | name  | email | pass | created_at |
-------------------------------------------
 1   |   A   | a@g.c | 123  | 2017-10-21 |
-------------------------------------------
 2   |   B   | b@g.c | 123  | 2017-10-21 |
```

in my `Page` model i used:

```
public function createdBy(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','created_by','id');
}
```

now when i am trying to get the data with:

```
$model = Page::all()
foreach($model as $key => $value){

     echo $value->createdBy->name."<br/>";
}
```

laravel generating multiple queries to get name of each user is that any way to run the join instead of multiple queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running into the `N+1` problem. You need to eager load your relationship to resolve this. You can read more on [eager loading here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Use the `with()` method on the page query to eager load all the related user records for each page:

```
$model = Page::with('createdBy')->get();
foreach ($model as $key => $value) {
    echo $value->createdBy->name."<br/>";
}
```

This will now only run 2 queries: one to get all the pages, and one to get all the users related to each page.

Comment: @RahulSharma You still need to access `$model[0]->createdBy->name`. I added in the rest of your original code to show that it wouldn't change.

Comment: Yea! its running two queries only now: `select * from `pages`` and `select * from `users` where `users`.`id` in ('1', '2')`.. but i just amazed about we calling this `RELATIONSHIP` and we always hear relation means joins in database vocabulary..

Comment: so this thing will fast or joins will fast ?

Comment: @RahulSharma Well, theoretically joins would be faster since it would only be one query instead of two, but you probably don't want to waste hours and hours of development and maintenance time to save <1 millisecond. And, if you get to the point where you're returning enough records that a join versus two queries matters, you have bigger issues than that (trying to load a million `Model` objects, for example).

Answer (score 1):

For that reason `Laravel` provides `eager Loading`

**Eager Loading**

When accessing Eloquent relationships as properties, the relationship data is "lazy loaded". This means the relationship data is not actually loaded until you first access the property. However, `Eloquent` can "eager load" relationships at the time you query the parent model

For more info just check this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

OR Just Use `Laravel's` database query builder

You can perform join directly on your Table and fetch directly the data

```
 $users =  DB::table('pages')
         ->join('users', 'pages.created_by', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('users.name','users.email', 'pages.*') //Specify what parameters you want.
        ->get();
```

Comment: what it does mean? why laravel not creating join, why they running separate query in `Eager Loading` ?

Comment: `Laravel` provide both method `Eloquent` and `DB` instance for querying. If you use `DB` you have to write all the query manually. With Eloquent there is problem called `N+1`. To solve it they provide eager loading. TO better understand Just check this link http://kamranahmed.info/blog/2014/12/07/eager-loading-in-laravel/

Answer (score 0):

To Join queries you can use laravel query builder like below

```
$pages = DB::table('pages')
        ->join('users', 'pages.created_by', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('users.*', 'pages.*')
        ->get();
```